# Query Relevance Rewriting in Ontology

Tags: jena, ontology, owl-api

I was wondering is there a way/work that focuses only on those axioms that are needed to answer the query and based on this rewrite the query, instead of finding the whole TBox closure? Mostly the work that I have come across related to query rewriting uses the whole TBox closure. Here is one of the references for [Query Rewriting](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226409092_Tractable_Reasoning_and_Efficient_Query_Answering_in_Description_Logics_The_DL-LiteFamily). Is it even possible without the whole TBox closure or I am missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: It is possible to answer a query with just the relevant axioms, the difficulty is how to define which axioms are relevant. Query answering and classification are not exactly the same problem, however I believe the modularisation and atomic decomposition research areas provide techniques for creating modules - i.e., subsets of axioms from the start ontology - that would do just what you're after. OWLAPI contains utilities for atomic decomposition, although they're based on research that has been published about ten years ago - so there might be better implementations around.

Comment: @Ignazio Thank you for the insight. Do you know any paper/work, where I can read these techniques?

Comment: if not wrong @Ignazio you are talking about something like this http://owl.cs.manchester.ac.uk/research/modularity/#:~:text=A%20locality%2Dbased%20module%20M,a%20seed%20signature%20of%20M.

Comment: indeed - Chiara Del Vescovo's phd thesis is the newest work on the topic that I know about https://www.research.manchester.ac.uk/portal/en/theses/the-modular-structure-of-an-ontology-atomic-decomposition-and-its-applications(f350ebd0-7030-49ab-8052-4ab94d38719c).html

Comment: @Ignazio I have come across Chainsaw and I think this is what I was looking for. But I want to test it before jumping to any conclusion. I am trying to compile this project in Eclipse but I am getting errors on "libFaCTPlusPlusJNI.jnilib", which I have replaced with "FaCTpp-OWLAPI-3.4-v1.6.3.jar" and on "owlapi-bin.jar", which I have replaced with "owlapi-distribution-3.4.3-bin.jar". But there are still errors which I believe are due to library changes. I have made an issue also on the repository. Can you please provide a working directory/src of Chainsaw?

Comment: See latest comment on chainsaw issue tracker